# Magento 2 preference not working for Magento\Customer\Model\Metadata\Form\File

Tags: image, plugin, upload, preference, file

I want to create preference for this file Magento\Customer\Model\Metadata\Form\File but its not working so please give some solution for this problem how to solve it

di.xml code

Comment: Please add your code so we can see what you tried.

Comment: Try to share your xml file where you are trying to give override

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks correct. And if you instantiate the `Magento\Customer\Model\Metadata\Form\File` you should get an instance of your own class.
But maybe it does not work for you because you are not using directly the class `Magento\Customer\Model\Metadata\Form\File`.
I see that there is another class `Magento\Customer\Model\Metadata\Form\Image` that extends the `Magento\Customer\Model\Metadata\Form\File`. Maybe your code uses this `Image` class and not the `File` class.
If this is the case you need to create a preference for the image class to work because the Image class still extends the original File class and not your new clsss.